# Gradle, gae, appengine-web.xml and web.xml not found

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I have just started with gae plugin. The problem is that when I run gradle gaeRun I get the exception:

com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate ../myapp/build/exploded-war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

So far I managed to get round the problem by adding the following in my gradle.build script:

```
gaeRun.doFirst{
copy {
    from('war/WEB-INF/') {
        include '**/*'
    }

    into 'build/exploded-war/WEB-INF/'
 }
}
```

Is that the correct approach? Below is the whole script:

```
apply plugin: 'gae'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'scala'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.0'
}

buildscript {
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies { 
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-gae-plugin:0.7.6' 
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
scalaTools 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.1'
scalaTools 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.1'

compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.1'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
}

gae {
httpPort = 8085
optimizeWar = true

appcfg {
    email = 'email@gmail.com'
    passIn = true

    logs {
        severity = 1
        outputFile = file('mylogs.txt')
    }

    app { id = 'sample-app' }
}
}

gaeRun.doFirst{
    copy {
        from('war/WEB-INF/') {
        include '**/*'
    }

        into 'build/exploded-war/WEB-INF/'
 }
}
```

Comment: Does your project contain the file `appengine-web.xml`? You do not need to add the action `doFirst` on the task `gaeRun`. The plugin automatically explodes your WAR file to `build/exploded-war` if you do not set the convention property `warDir`. Is your project publicly available so we can have a look at it?